# Why do I get errors when I try to fire stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

I use SQL Server 2012.

I need to pass an array of integers to my stored procedure from Visual Studio. I need to use passed array in `where` clause.

For this purpose I created `table valued parameter`:

```
CREATE TYPE IdArray AS TABLE 
(
     Id int
);
```

And here my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_TEST_TLP]
    @List dbo.IdArray READONLY 
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    FROM Clients 
    WHERE Clients.Id IN ( '@List' )
END
```

But I try to fire the stored procedure and passing values (some integers) in execute procedure window, I get this error:

> Must pass parameter number 2 and subsequent parameters as '@name = value'. After the form '@name = value' has been used, all subsequent parameters must be passed in the form '@name = value'.

**UPDATE:**

Here how I call the stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SP_TEST_TLP]
        @List = 1,6

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Any idea why I get this error? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want us to point out what you are doing wrong, post the code you are using to execute the proc. Also, do not use `sp_` as a stored procedure name prefix.  That denotes a SQL Server system stored procedure. Do not enclose the TVP is quotes. Instead, specify a subquery like `SELECT id FROM @List`.

Comment: `Where Clients.Id IN ( '@List' )` won't do what you want either. You were already given the correct syntax here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206849/why-i-get-error-when-i-try-to-create-stored-procedure

Comment: Can you get the code that execute procedure windows produces? Execute procedure windows uses @name = value syntax for calling SPs. If you're just writing the numbers in a comma separated way (1, 2, 3) then most probably it will be interpreted as `@List = 1, 2 ,3` and that's not what you want.

Comment: @DanGuzman, I have multiple declares of  table valued types in my stored procedure and I need to implement multiple where filters.That what I try:

`ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_TEST_TLP]

    @List dbo.IdArray READONLY, 
 @List2 dbo.IdArray READONLY 

AS 
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 select * from Clients Where Clients.Id IN (select id from @List)  and  (select id from @List2)
END`


But it is wrong.How can I implement it?

Comment: @Michael, both subqueries must be introduced with the `IN` keyword.  Try `WHERE Clients.Id IN (SELECT id FROM @List) AND Clients.Id IN (SELECT id FROM @List2)`.

Comment: @DanGuzman, thanks its really helped me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table valued types and parameters in TSQL are little different then you've conceived.

Table valued parameters are basically tables, not arrays or lists. You cannot use comma seperated syntax to specify multiple values.

You should do it like

```
DECLARE @return_value int
DECLARE @MyList AS dbo.IdArray

INSERT INTO @MyList (Id) 
VALUES (1),(6)

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[SP_TEST_TLP] @List = @MyList

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

I guess you cannot do this with *Execute Stored Procedure* interface.

And in stored procedure body you should use `@List` like you'll use any table name. Your `... IN ( '$List' )...` construct won't work. You need to use a join or a subquery. Remember, `@List` is a table.

Comment: thank you.Do you  have any idea how can I pass int array from visual studio to populate the  table valued parameter?

Comment: @Michael, pass a parameter of type System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured. The value can be a `DataTable`, `DataRow[]`, or `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`. A DataTable containing the list of integers is probably easiest.